# Handling Zoomed View in iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, zooming

I created iOS app and it works perfect on all iPhone resolutions. I'm facing one typical scenario in which the app is not behaving the same.
On iPhone6, enable the option in "Settings->Display & Brightness->View->Zoomed"
In my application, I've "Start" button at the bottom of the view. In Zoomed state, the button is going below the screen and so user is not able to tap "Start" button.
Is there any setting that I've to enable in the app or write any specific code to handle the "Zoomed" state in the application?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?